# Newly Arrived message is not retrieving from my own Default SMS App Inbox

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider, android-broadcastreceiver

I am working on a project in which I have made **app to default sms** app and getting new message body and notification through Broadcast Receiver. It is showing toast that new message has been received and also read new message body.

But problems are

**Problem 1:**

The newly received sms is not retrieving from my default sms app inbox and not showing in my listview.

**Problem 2:**

I am not able to get each and every message from  each conversation

**GetMessage() code:**

```
 public ArrayList<String> getSms() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver=getContentResolver();
        Uri mSmsQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = contentResolver.query(mSmsQueryUri, new String[] { "_id", "address", "date", "body",
                    "type", "read" }, null, null, "date desc");
            if (cursor == null) {
                Log.i("curson null", "cursor is null. uri: " + mSmsQueryUri);
                Toast.makeText(this, "curor null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            for (boolean hasData = cursor.moveToFirst(); hasData; hasData = cursor.moveToNext()) {

                String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
                String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
               /* String date= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD",Locale.US);
                Date datee= dateFormat.parse(date);*/

                messages.add("\n"+ "Sender:     "+ address+"\n"+"Content:      "+body+"\n");
                //messages.add(address);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

        return messages;
    }
```

**MyListner code**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Getting new Message notification
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
            Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();



            if(bundle!=null){
                Toast.makeText(context, "New Message Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {

                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    SmsMessage[] msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++) {
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                        message_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                         msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                    }
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Message sent from:  " + message_from, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if(msgBody.equals("Where are you")){
                            sendMessage(context);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Message Body:       " + msgBody, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Other message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When your app is the default, it is responsible for saving incoming messages to the Provider. Since you're not doing that, those messages aren't going to be in your query results.

Comment: Yes. i m making mistake. I haven't see this question which link you have given.

Comment: So thanks for helping and reference.

Comment: No problem. I would also mention that the default app should really be processing the `SMS_DELIVER` broadcast, instead of `SMS_RECEIVED`.

Comment: @MikeM. will you please tell me how can i delete complete inbox (defuaut) from my app which is not default ? is there any way ?

Comment: i am in huge issue. you have experience in sms for android . please guide me

Comment: "will you please tell me how can i delete complete inbox (defuaut) from my app which is not default ?" – You can't, really. There was a bug in 4.4 (KitKat) whereby a non-default app could get write access to the SMS Provider, but they fixed it in later versions. Since then, only the default app can delete messages on a standard system.

Comment: @MikeM.  is there another way to  delete or abort message  before reaching to inbox without abortBroadcast() .......   bacause it is not working for me even i set my app(not default) to 999 or 1000. but  message is also delived to inbox...

Comment: i am stuck from two days. can you please help me out ?

Comment: No, since 4.4 (KitKat), `abortBroadcast()` is ignored for the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast. Furthermore, the default app, which is what's writing those messages to the inbox, gets a different broadcast – `SMS_DELIVER` – which no other app gets, and which cannot be aborted or prevented anyway. On a standard system, since KitKat, there is no way to block or delete incoming text messages unless your app is the default. People have been trying to do that since it came about, and, apart from the bug in 4.4 I mentioned above, there is no way to do it.

Comment: @MikeM. when i make my  app default and i am using  this line context.getContentResolver().delete(Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI, null,null)  to delete system app inbox(which is not default now) completely but this is not giving me expected results?  what will be the possible reasons  ?

Comment: What results are you seeing, exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186730/discussion-between-muhammad-ashfaq-and-mike-m).